# Augmented image detection is not working fine when device ARCore updated to 1.11.0

Tags: android, arcore, onupdate, sceneview

Augmented Image detection is working perfectly with 1.10.0 when I updated the ARCore version from 1.10.0 to 1.11.0 then ARSceneview is not detecting the augmented images trackables from  updated frame in addUpdateListener in Android. Due to full_trcking it is proving image results of previous frame not based on latest frame.

```
private fun onUpdateFrame(frameTime: FrameTime) {
intIndex = intIndex+1;
if (isComputingFrame){
    Log.e("Frames", "Dropped")
    }else {
    isComputingFrame = true
    val frame = getViewDataBinding().arSceneView.arFrame
    val colorCorrectionRgba = FloatArray(4)
    frame?.getLightEstimate()?.getColorCorrection(colorCorrectionRgba, 0)
    handler?.post {
        if (frame != null) {
            Log.e("Frames","image index --> "+intIndex)
            getViewModel()?.processFrameForDetection(frame)
            } else {
            isComputingFrame = false;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Did not get any error message